# Which order to install Visual Studio and SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database-administration

I search many question regarding installation sequence but i want  to find the solution of this problem...

I install SQL Server 2014 which is running correctly.

Now I install Visual Studio 2015 and .Net 4.6 before installing V.S which stop the execution of SQL Server. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: My sequence to install these>>>> 1st SQL Server 2014.  2nd .Net 4.6   3rd Visual studio 2015.   When i install .net 4.6 framework it stop the running of sql server.

Comment: Does VS2015 install SQL? That could be why.

Comment: yes.  visual studio install this.